# Unable run "npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.4.0 @stripe/stripe-js@1.13.2 -s"

Tags: python, reactjs, npm, stripe-payments

As title, when I trying run the **npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.4.0 @stripe/stripe-js@1.13.2 -s** in the terminal but failed to install.

It just simply show like this
[image: Error message in the terminal]

When I try to run **npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.4.0 @stripe/stripe-js@1.13.2** which without **-s**, it shows the following messages in the terminal:

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/react@13.4.0

npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.2" from @restart/context@2.1.4

npm ERR!   node_modules/@restart/context

npm ERR!     @restart/context@"^2.1.4" from react-bootstrap@1.5.2

npm ERR!     node_modules/react-bootstrap

npm ERR!       react-bootstrap@"^1.5.2" from the root project

npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @restart/hooks@0.3.27

npm ERR!   node_modules/@restart/hooks

npm ERR!     @restart/hooks@"^0.3.26" from react-bootstrap@1.5.2

npm ERR!     node_modules/react-bootstrap

npm ERR!       react-bootstrap@"^1.5.2" from the root project

npm ERR!   19 more (prop-types-extra, qrcode.react, react-bootstrap, ...)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0

npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react

npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0

npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react

npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! See /Users/chingkarlok/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/chingkarlok/.npm/_logs/2022-10-06T03_42_21_140Z-debug-0.log

[image: Full error messages]

Below is the complete log of this run that found in **/Users/chingkarlok/.npm/_logs/2022-10-06T03_42_21_140Z-debug-0.log**

```
1 info using npm@8.15.0
2 info using node@v16.17.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Users/chingkarlok/Desktop/QRMenu/qrmenu_frontend/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/chingkarlok/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 5ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 5ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 2ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
22 verbose title npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.4.0 @stripe/stripe-js@1.13.2
23 verbose argv "install" "@stripe/react-stripe-js@1.4.0" "@stripe/stripe-js@1.13.2"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 9ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/chingkarlok/.npm/_logs
28 verbose logfile /Users/chingkarlok/.npm/_logs/2022-10-06T03_42_21_140Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 2ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 1ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 22ms
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
34 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
35 silly logfile done cleaning log files
36 timing idealTree:init Completed in 325ms
37 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 1ms
38 silly idealTree buildDeps
39 silly fetch manifest @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.4.0
40 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
41 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@stripe%2freact-stripe-js 265ms (cache hit)
42 silly fetch manifest @stripe/stripe-js@1.13.2
43 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@stripe%2fstripe-js 5ms (cache hit)
44 silly fetch manifest react@^17.0.2
45 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 5ms (cache hit)
46 silly fetch manifest react-dom@^17.0.2
47 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom 5ms (cache hit)
48 silly placeDep ROOT @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.4.0 OK for: qrmenu_frontend@0.1.0 want: 1.4.0
49 silly placeDep ROOT @stripe/stripe-js@1.13.2 OK for: @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.4.0 want: ^1.13.0
50 silly placeDep ROOT @stripe/stripe-js@1.13.2 REPLACE for: qrmenu_frontend@0.1.0 want: 1.13.2
51 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 303ms
52 timing idealTree:node_modules/@stripe/react-stripe-js Completed in 0ms
53 timing idealTree:node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js Completed in 0ms
54 silly fetch manifest react@^18.0.0
55 silly fetch manifest react-dom@^18.0.0
56 timing idealTree Completed in 632ms
57 timing command:install Completed in 641ms
58 verbose stack Error: could not resolve
58 verbose stack     at PlaceDep.failPeerConflict (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/place-dep.js:549:25)
58 verbose stack     at PlaceDep.place (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/place-dep.js:199:21)
58 verbose stack     at new PlaceDep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/place-dep.js:73:10)
58 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:990:31
58 verbose stack     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
58 verbose stack     at Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:990:8)
58 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:218:7)
58 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
58 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:154:5)
58 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:145:5)
59 verbose cwd /Users/chingkarlok/Desktop/QRMenu/qrmenu_frontend
60 verbose Darwin 20.3.0
61 verbose node v16.17.0
62 verbose npm  v8.15.0
63 error code ERESOLVE
64 error ERESOLVE could not resolve
65 error
66 error While resolving: [1m@testing-library/react[22m@[1m13.4.0[22m
66 error Found: [1mreact[22m@[1m17.0.2[22m[2m[22m
66 error [2mnode_modules/react[22m
66 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m>=16.3.2[22m" from [1m@restart/context[22m@[1m2.1.4[22m[2m[22m
66 error   [2mnode_modules/@restart/context[22m
66 error     [1m@restart/context[22m@"[1m^2.1.4[22m" from [1mreact-bootstrap[22m@[1m1.5.2[22m[2m[22m
66 error     [2mnode_modules/react-bootstrap[22m
66 error       [1mreact-bootstrap[22m@"[1m^1.5.2[22m" from the root project
66 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m>=16.8.0[22m" from [1m@restart/hooks[22m@[1m0.3.27[22m[2m[22m
66 error   [2mnode_modules/@restart/hooks[22m
66 error     [1m@restart/hooks[22m@"[1m^0.3.26[22m" from [1mreact-bootstrap[22m@[1m1.5.2[22m[2m[22m
66 error     [2mnode_modules/react-bootstrap[22m
66 error       [1mreact-bootstrap[22m@"[1m^1.5.2[22m" from the root project
66 error   19 more (prop-types-extra, qrcode.react, react-bootstrap, ...)
66 error
66 error Could not resolve dependency:
66 error [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m^18.0.0[22m" from [1m@testing-library/react[22m@[1m13.4.0[22m[2m[22m
66 error [2mnode_modules/@testing-library/react[22m
66 error   [1m@testing-library/react[22m@"[1m^13.4.0[22m" from the root project
66 error
66 error Conflicting peer dependency: [1mreact[22m@[1m18.2.0[22m[2m[22m
66 error [2mnode_modules/react[22m
66 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m^18.0.0[22m" from [1m@testing-library/react[22m@[1m13.4.0[22m[2m[22m
66 error   [2mnode_modules/@testing-library/react[22m
66 error     [1m@testing-library/react[22m@"[1m^13.4.0[22m" from the root project
66 error
66 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
66 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
66 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
66 error
66 error See /Users/chingkarlok/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
67 verbose exit 1
68 timing npm Completed in 723ms
69 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1665027741218
70 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1665027741226
71 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1665027741552
72 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:node_modules/@testing-library/react 1665027741855
73 verbose code 1
74 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
74 error     /Users/chingkarlok/.npm/_logs/2022-10-06T03_42_21_140Z-debug-0.log
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "qrmenu_frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "qrcode.react": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.7",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

May I know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a dependency conflict between react@18.2.0 and react@17.0.2. Why don't you just run

```
npm install --save @stripe/react-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js
```

like [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#setup) suggested?

Comment: I see. Sorry I am a beginner. May I know how to resolve the dependency conflict that you mentioned? Also **npm install --save @stripe/react-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js** doesn't work as well.